# Changing the install directory of RubyGems on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, scoop-installer

For some reason, RubyGems keeps installing gems in the directory of the old Scoop Ruby installation that I've wiped. Can I change the directory? I'm trying to find all my options before going straight to WSL. Thank you.

Comment: Use command `gem env` to check the environment and what config it is picking up from where. It could be `GEM_HOME` has been set. In that case you can set it to some place else or just remove it completely and Ruby should revert to its default installation folder.

Comment: If that's what you're talking about, `SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY` is set to `C:/ProgramData`. Can't find anything Ruby in there.

Comment: Post the full output of `gem env`, and from DOS prompt the output of `echo %GEM_HOME%`.

Answer (score 0):

The location of installed gems is determined by two things:

1. What is compiled into the Ruby executable.
   On `gem env` this is `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, unless... (see below).
2. The `GEM_HOME` environment variable which will override the default `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`.

So, if you want to change `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, then you have two choices for a fix:

1. Install another Ruby version which will have a different default `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` (determined at compile time).
2. Set the `GEM_HOME` environment variable to any location that you prefer.

A related env variable is `GEM_PATH`, which will list all locations where Ruby will look for gems. The lookup folders will be listed in `gem env` under `GEM PATHS`, and can be altered by yourself by setting the `GEM_PATH` env variable on your machine.

This way the combination of `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`, `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`, determines how Ruby installs and where it finds its gems.